# What does node write to stderr?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stderr

I know that node writes to stderr if there is an uncaught exception:

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

or if it encounters a console.error('some error yo');

https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_error_data_args

But in what other contexts would node write to `stderr`? I'm wondering would a `throw new Error()` cause node to write the error to `stderr` or a `unknown rangeError` or do those just get written to `stdout`? I can't find confirmation either way of this in the node docs.

Comment: You could try these things directly yourself fairly easily, but technically anything can write directly to process.stderr, so any libraries or app code could write there.

Comment: Ok great. How can I monitor that something has been written to `stderr`? I understand that anything "can" write to stderr but what I'm after is info on whether Js errors (syntax, range, type for example) and errors generated via `throw new error` get written to `stderr`

Comment: I suppose you could monitor process.stderr with `process.stderr.on('data', ...);`, but you can just check what goes to stderr from where you execute it?
As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331205/bash-print-stderr-only-not-stdout

You could try `node index.js > /dev/null`